# How to connect .NET code to node red platform

Tags: .net, node.js, mosquitto

I am having a .net code which is looking for a threshold value to send a message.I want this to light up an ledborg.
I am using node-red platform and  mosquitto-message broker to connect to the ledborg on a raspberry pi.
But still confused on how to put the message from .net to nodered platform.
Is there any message brokers we can use or something?? I am new to this area.

Comment: i've got zero experience on raspberry pi or any of the other platforms you've mentioned here, but I've done some work on message brokers. so fwiw, does mosquitto have a .net and node clients? if yes, is it possible for you to publish a message from the .net client and subscribe from the node client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the node-red platform but if it communicates with mosquitto, you 'll probably be able to use this MQTT lib http://m2mqtt.codeplex.com/ to send messages to mosquitto.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

There is [edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) project, which allow you to run .net code from node.js and run node.js code from .net.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EdgeJs;

class Program
{
public static async void Start()
{
    var func = Edge.Func(@"
        return function (data, callback) {
            callback(null, 'Node.js welcomes ' + data);
        }
    ");

    Console.WriteLine(await func(".NET"));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run((Action)Start).Wait();
}
}
```